# Set vertical scroller style in NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsscrollview, nsscroller

How can I set the vertical scroller style in `NSScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Interface Builder, deselect "automatically hide scrollers". The scroll bars then become visible. Click a scroll bar and edit its control size attributes in the inspector.

If you're doing this in code:

```
NSScrollView* myScrollView = ...;
[[myScrollView verticalScroller] setControlSize: NSSmallControlSize]; // or whatever
```

Comment: How about in Xcode? Can I edit its control size attributes in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set the size in Xcode.
Or rather in Interface Builder:

[image]

Make sure to expand the objects panel on the left.
Then you can see two `NSScroller` objects in the scroll view.
Just select them and set the control size in the Inspector Panel to `Small` or `Mini`.